# Semantic Search

Tags: unsupervised-learning, word-embeddings, similarity, similar-documents, semantic-similarity

There is a problem we are trying to solve where we want to do semantic search on our set of data,
i.e we have a domain specific data (example: sentences talking about automobiles)

Our data is just a bunch of sentences and what we want is to give a phrase and get back the sentences which are:

1. Similar to that phrase
2. Has a part of sentence that is similar to the phrase
3. Sentence which is having contextually similar meanings

Let me try giving you an example suppose I search for the phrase "Buying Experience", I should get the sentences like:

I never thought car buying could take less than 30 minutes to sign and buy.

I found a car that i liked and the purchase process was straightforward and easy

I absolutely hated going car shopping, but today i’m glad i did

I want to lay emphasis on the fact that we are looking for contextual similarity and not just a brute force word search.

If the sentence uses different words then also it should be able to find it.

Things that we have already tried:

1. Open Semantic Search (https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/) the problem we faced here is generating ontology from the data we have, or
   for that sake searching for available ontology from different domains of our interest.
2. Elastic Search(BM25 + Vectors(tf-idf)), we tried this where it gave a few sentences but precision was not that great. The accuracy was bad
   as well. We tried against a human curated dataset, it was able to get around 10% of the sentences only.
3. We tried different embeddings like the once mentioned in https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers and also went through the example
   https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/application_semantic_search.py and tried evaluating against our human curated set
   and that also had a very low accuracy.
4. We tried ELMO(https://towardsdatascience.com/elmo-contextual-language-embedding-335de2268604) this was better but still lower accuracy than we expected and there is a
   cognitive load to decide the cosine value below which we shouldn't consider the sentences. This even apply to point 3.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Comment: Have you tried BERT? It's a pre-trained transfer learning model that you can feed your context-specific data into.

Comment: Yes we tried BERT and did a Transfer Learning on it with our domain data it didn't give good result. We tried Bert Large model to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Similar to that phrase

You can try Phrase-BERT for phrase embeddings.

- Paper: *Wang, Shufan, Laure Thompson, and Mohit Iyyer. "[Phrase-BERT: Improved Phrase Embeddings from BERT with an Application to Corpus Exploration.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.06304.pdf)" EMNLP 2021*.
- [Code](https://github.com/sf-wa-326/phrase-bert-topic-model).

The paper also mentions related previous work, e.g. SentBERT and SpanBERT.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the word mover's distance (WMD) algorithm. WMD can find the distance between two documents in a meaningful way even when they have no words in common by finding the most efficient way to move the distribution one document to another document. The WMD algorithm can use any word or phrase embeddings.